# Solving modular equations for solutions.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $k, p, q$, we need to find the solutions for

> $x ^{k}\equiv p$ (mod $q)$.

How to find the number of solutions for $x$ up to some upper limit of $x$.

Comment: Project Euler??

Comment: Are $k,p,q$ each arbitrary positive integers, or are $p$ and/or $q$ meant to be prime?

Comment: Yes, they are arbitrary positive integers and p is less than q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $x$ is a solution if and only if $x+aq$ is for some integer $a$. Therefore you can brute force this by checking $x=0,1,2,\ldots,q-1$ and using the above observation from that point on.

There are several shortcuts for specific inputs $q,k$. For example, if $q$ is a prime, and $k$ has no common divisors with $q-1$, then we know that in the range
$0\le x<q$ there will be exactly one solution irrespective of the value of $p$. Such shortcuts rely on an understanding of the multiplicative structure of the ring
$\mathbb{Z}_q$ and its group of units.